# Apply class to div from content within another div

Tags: jquery, addition

Im currently using a script (that is working) where I can apply a certain class to a div, based on the class of another div. I would prefer to use content:contains(), to determine the class of the other div, but when I use it, it applies every class at the same time, from every `if` statement. The code im using is below.

```
// Set Olympic
            if($(".reg-status.olympic span").hasClass("open")) {
                $(".reg-status-view.olympic").addClass("open");
            }
            if($(".reg-status.olympic span").hasClass("waiting")) {
                $(".reg-status-view.olympic").addClass("waiting");
            }
            if($(".reg-status.olympic span").hasClass("closed")) {
                $(".reg-status-view.olympic").addClass("closed");
            }

            // Set Long Course
            if($(".reg-status.long-course span").hasClass("open")) {
                $(".reg-status-view.long-course").addClass("open");
            }
            if($(".reg-status.long-course span").hasClass("waiting")) {
                $(".reg-status-view.long-course").addClass("waiting");
            }
            if($(".reg-status.long-course span").hasClass("closed")) {
                $(".reg-status-view.long-course").addClass("closed");
            }
```

Question 1: Is there a cleaner way to do what im current trying
Question 2: How do I `.addClass` from content with the initial div, as appose to the class on the initial div.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your HTML look like? Can you add a representative sample to your question?

Comment: See sample here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/trobbins26/CD7Mq/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, put the searches into a reference variable to prevent re-searching the dom. second, if the source div only contains "open","closed","waiting" classes, you can copy the class attribute to the target div.

```
var olySrcDiv = $(".reg-status.olympic span");
var olyTgtDiv = $(".reg-status-view.olympic");
olyTgtDiv.attr("class",olyTgtDiv.attr("class") + " " + olySrcDiv.attr("class"));

var lngSrcDiv = $(".reg-status.long-course span");
var lngTgtDiv = $(".reg-status-view.long-course");
lngTgtDiv.attr("class",lngTgtDiv.attr("class") + " " + lngSrcDiv.attr("class"));
```

Comment: Great ideas, however I don't want to replace the classes on lngTgtDiv, i want to add to it. I think thats the only thing missing from this, however I'm not sure how to change  the third line correctly to addClass(from var lngSrcDiv)

In addition i wanted to add from SrcDiv, and not from a class

Comment: Working now. Thankyou. Do you have a suggestion on how to modify this code to reference text within the span as appose to the class on the span? Thankyou

Comment: `.reg-status.long-course span:contains("open")` might work but you still would need to check all in three lines.

Comment: Tried it with no luck, however I'm not sure what you  mean by check all in three lines. Maybe I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: Tpaksu, Any final thoughts on this, in regard to referencing content as appose to classes?

Comment: I'll give it a try. I'll update my answer when I finish trying.